# Replace words in text found within <p> tags while using a lookup array

Tags: php, preg-replace, lookup, domparser

I am trying to write a script which is looking for keywords in text and replacing them with anchor tags (links).

I would only like to change text in paragraph tags (`<p>`), so heading tags (`<h[123456]>`) should remain unchanged.

I am looking for a `preg_replace` pattern which can replace text only in paragraphs.

```
$keywords = array(
    'keywords' => 'www.1.com',
    'hello' => 'www.2.com',
    'there' => 'www.3.com',
    'are' => 'www.4.com',
);

$sentence = '
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Hello there blablabla</h2>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
';

foreach ($keywords as $word => $link){
    $sentence = preg_replace('@(?<=\W|^)('.$word.')(?=\W|$)@i', '<a href="'.$link.'">$1</a>', $sentence, 1);
}

echo $sentence;
```

Comment: use [`str_ireplace `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) in place of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: check this replace your loop with this `echo str_replace(array_keys($keywords), array_values($keywords), $sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

This probably comes close to what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$keywords = array(
    'keywords' => 'www.1.com',
    'hello' => 'www.2.com',
    'there' => 'www.3.com',
    'are' => 'www.4.com',
);

$sentence = <<<TEXT
<h1>Hello, here we have a keyword!</h1>
<h2>Hello there is some sub title</h2>
<p>Hello, there are some hidden keywords in here</p>
<p>Hello, here are some additional keywords</p>
<p>Hello, there we have more keywords</p>
<p>Hello, and keywords</p>
<p>Hello, but no more hello wherever you look...</p>
<p>Hello, there is also a <a href="...">link</a> in here!</p>

TEXT;

foreach ($keywords as $word => $link) {
    $pattern = '|^(<p[^>]*>.*)(' . preg_quote($word, '|') . ')(.*</p>)$|mui';
    $replace = '$1<a href="' . $link . '">$2</a>$3';
    $sentence = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $sentence);
}
echo $sentence;
```

The output of above code is:

```
<h1>Hello, here we have a keyword!</h1>
<h2>Hello there is some sub title</h2>
<p><a href="www.2.com">Hello</a>, <a href="www.3.com">there</a> <a href="www.4.com">are</a> some hidden <a href="www.1.com">keywords</a> in here</p>
<p><a href="www.2.com">Hello</a>, here <a href="www.4.com">are</a> some additional <a href="www.1.com">keywords</a></p>
<p><a href="www.2.com">Hello</a>, <a href="www.3.com">there</a> we have more <a href="www.1.com">keywords</a></p>
<p><a href="www.2.com">Hello</a>, and <a href="www.1.com">keywords</a></p>
<p>Hello, but no more <a href="www.2.com">hello</a> wherever you look...</p>
<p><a href="www.2.com">Hello</a>, <a href="www.3.com">there</a> is also a <a href="...">link</a> in here!</p>
```

You will however never get an absolute robust solution with an approach based only on regular expressions. You should consider using a DOM parser to handle the complexity of the HTML markup. Then inside the parsed elements you can apply pattern replacement.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers, but i just need script witch will ignore h1,h2,h3 tags inside text

Comment: @lop432 Not sure what you mean by that. The code does what you asked for in your question. If you think otherwise then please explain how.

Comment: Hmm, it is possible to preg_replace ignore all HTML tags?
So $sentence = preg_replace('@(?<=\W|^)('.$word.')(?=\W|$)@i', '<a href="'.$link.'">$1</a>', $sentence, 1); stay same . And then I need just add in preg_replace to ignore all HTML tags. And  keywords will be replaced with anchore tags

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "ignore all HTML tags". If you process HTML markup, then you cannot ignore them, since the whole markup consists _only_ of tags, tags inside tags inside tags. In your question you state that you want to replace keywords inside paragraphs, you explicitly name the `<p>` tag yourself. So now you want something completely different?

Comment: Can you please check your code, I don't get keywords replaced with urls. i get clean paragraphs without links

Comment: I check all code I post in answers myself. It works for me and delivery exactly the result I posted. So the question is: what is different when you test it? Where does your test differ from the situation you described in your own question?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must not get into the habit of trying to parse valid html with regex.  It is much more reliable to parse html with a legitimate dom parsing library.  I like DOMDocument.  If your *actual* input string doesn't have a parent/containing element for your posted elements, you'll need to stabilize the DOM structure by wrapping the input string in a `<div></div>` tag, then remove the wrapper after processing is complete.
2. Use `getElementsByTagName()` to isolate the `<p>` tags in the document, then loop over this refined collection.
3. Use `preg_replace_callback()` to perform a replacement based on your lookup array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qdl34))

```
$keywords = [
    'keywords' => 'www.1.com',
    'hello' => 'www.2.com',
    'there' => 'www.3.com',
    'are' => 'www.4.com',
];

$sentence = '
<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Hello there blablabla</h2>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
    <p>Hello, there are keywords</p>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($sentence, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    $p->nodeValue = preg_replace_callback(
        '~\b(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($keywords)) . ')\b~i',
        function($m) use ($keywords) {
            return $keywords[strtolower($m[0])];
        },
        $p->nodeValue
    );
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Hello there blablabla</h2>
    <p>www.2.com, www.3.com www.4.com www.1.com</p>
    <p>www.2.com, www.3.com www.4.com www.1.com</p>
    <p>www.2.com, www.3.com www.4.com www.1.com</p>
    <p>www.2.com, www.3.com www.4.com www.1.com</p>
    <p>www.2.com, www.3.com www.4.com www.1.com</p>
</div>
```